# How to write recursive functions

Tags: function, recursion

How to write recursive functions? Could you explain me the principle of recursion in functions, ideally with some examples like factorial or fibonacci sequence?

Comment: You write a recursive function by writing a recursive function. That's recursive. Get it?

Comment: I don't quite understand how the first term could be evaluated recursively.

Comment: http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-8-fractals/ has a good writeup

Comment: Now the question is edited, so it doesn't have to be on hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this way in Python:

```
def f( num ):
    if num == 0:
        return 1

    return num * f( num-1 )
```

This is the example of Factorial.

Generally, you return not only some value, but even calling the function itself, so it will run again with another parameter. Eventually it will stop immersing, when you return only a value without further calling the function (here we return 1 as the stopper).

For `num=3` it will be like this:

```
f(3)
  |
  return 3 * f(2)
               |
               return 2 * f(1)
                            |
                            return 1 * f(0)
                                         |
                                         return 1
```

Finally it goes backwards, so:

```
1 * 1 = 1
        |
        1 * 2 = 2
                |
                2 * 3 = 6
```

And that's our factorial :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the second sum can be calculated as follows in C#.

```
public static Sum(int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 ) // end of recursion, so-called "base case"
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else          // recursion
    {
        return n * n + Sum(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic pattern is

```
function(arg) 
    if baseCase 
        return fixedValue
    else
        modify arg
        return function(newArg)
```

so the power example

```
function int pow(int num) {
    if (num == 0 ) return 1;
    else return num ^ 2 + pow(--num);
}
```